# disable link if checkbox s unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable link if user uncheck the checkbox.

tried something like:

```
$('#check1').click(function() {
  if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#tet1').bind('click', function(){ return false; });
  }else{
    $('#tet1').unbind('click');
  }
});
```

but it did not work. http://jsfiddle.net/LX7wH/

Why this is not working for me? where i'm wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are after:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" />

$("a").click(function(e) {
        if($("#checkBox").prop("checked") === true) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        };
    });
```

This will stop all links working however you can change the "a" selector to what ever you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/KDZDE/

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to do anything when the checkbox is changed, just check if it's checked within an event handler for the anchor, and if it is checked, prevent the default action.

```
$('#tet1').on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $('#check1').is(':checked') ) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Dear OP please go with this solution. I did not think of this.

Comment: @AmitT. - Yet four years later you accept an answer that doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question ?

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
var xEnabled = true;

$('#check1').click(function() {
 xEnabled = $(this).is(':checked');
});

$('#tet1').click(function(){
   if(!xEnabled) { return false; }
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LX7wH/5/)